# Docker - NPM install local packages

Tags: node.js, docker

I am currently trying to install my NPM packages with Docker however, it's unable to do this for local packages? How do I fix this?

DockerFile:

```
FROM node:12

WORKDIR /var/api

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3010

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@hapi/joi": "^16.1.7",
    "@polka/send-type": "^0.5.2",
    "polka": "^0.5.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "core": "file:../core",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "ua-parser-js": "^0.7.21",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-duration-format": "^2.3.2",
    "node-schedule": "^1.3.2"
  },
```

Thanks.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @RamarajaRamanujan It builds fine when I try to run it, it says "cannot find module 'core'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
```

The problem is with those two lines, you are trying to install `"core": "file:../core"` but you never copied those dependencies to your image, so copy those dependencies along with the `package.json` and you will be good

Comment: Docker doesn't allow to copy anything above the current build context. So it won't copy from `../`.